# How to shuffle a vector except for the first and last elements without using third party libraries?

Tags: rust

I have a task to shuffle words but the first and last letter of every word must be unchanged. When I try to use `filter()` it doesn't work properly.

```
const SEPARATORS: &str = " ,;:!?./%*$=+)@_-('\"&1234567890\r\n";

fn main() {
    print!("MAIN:{:?}", mix("Evening,morning"));
}

fn mix(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut a: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();

    for group in a.split_mut(|num| SEPARATORS.contains(*num)) {
        if group.len() > 4 {
            let k = group.first().unwrap().clone();
            let c = group[group.len() - 1].clone();
            group
                .chunks_exact_mut(2)
                .filter(|x| x != &[k])
                .for_each(|x| x.swap(0, 1))
        }
    }

    let s: String = a.iter().collect();
    s
}
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want. Instead of writing `print!` in your example code, you could use `assert_eq!`, to show the result you expect, given the input.

Comment: e.g. `assert_eq!(mix("Evening,morning"), "Eorning,mvening");`

Comment: Take a look at [reprex] for how to improve your question and make it easier to answer.

Comment: Does `use rand::seq::SliceRandom; group[1..group.len()-1].shuffle();` do what you want? (See [`shuffle`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle))

Comment: Peter Hall, I want to shuffle letters in every word between first and last letter

Comment: Jmb, thanks, it could help, but I need to make it without third party libraries

Comment: Then you're out of luck: there is nothing for random values in the standard library. The `rand` crate is the accepted "standard" way to get random generators.

Comment: BTW, you should use an `@` in front of people's names when replying to their comments (eg. `@jmb` for me). That way we get a notification and we have less risk of missing your reply.

Comment: Jmp, thanks. Also I can use swap(0,1), it will be kind of "shuffle" but I can't skip first or last element. And when I'm using vectors I lose separator, but I need separator in my string.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```rust
fn mix(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut a: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();

    for words in a.split_mut(|num| SEPARATORS.contains(*num)) {
        if words.len() > 4 {
            let initial_letter = words.first().unwrap().clone();
            let last_letter = words[words.len() - 1].clone();
            words[0] = last_letter;
            words[words.len() - 1] = initial_letter;
        }
    }
    let s: String = a.iter().collect();
    s
}
```

Comment: I need to change order of letter between first and last letter of the word, but first and the last letter must not change.