# How to change order of letter in rust with swap?

Tags: rust

I need to change order in every word in sentence. I have string of separators to split my code into a words, and function `swap(0,1)` to change order of letters in word. However I need to skip first and last letter in every word and I can't use regular expressions for this purposes.
Here some code:

```
const SEPARATORS: &str = " ,;:!?./%*$=+)@_-('\"&1234567890\r\n";

fn main() {
    dbg!(mix("According, research"));
}

fn mix(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut a: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();

    for group in a.split_mut(|num| SEPARATORS.contains(*num)) {
        group.chunks_exact_mut(2).for_each(|x| x.swap(0, 1));
    }

    a.iter().collect()
}
```

Output as follows:

```
[src/main.rs:4] mix("According, research") = "cAocdrnig, eresrahc"
```

But I need output as follows:

```
[src/main.rs:4] mix("According, research") = "Accroidng, rseaerch"
```

Someone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: Is this from a quiz or tutorial or something? I've seen a few really similar questions in the last week.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576491/how-to-shuffle-a-vector-except-for-the-first-and-last-elements-without-using-thi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666177/how-to-change-order-of-letters-in-every-word-beside-first-and-last-letter-in-sen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use a slice that doesn't have the first and last character using `group[1..len-2]`:

```rust
const SEPARATORS: &str = " ,;:!?./%*$=+)@_-('\"&1234567890\r\n";

fn main() {
    dbg!(mix("According, research"));
}

fn mix(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut a: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();

    for group in a.split_mut(|num| SEPARATORS.contains(*num)) {
        let len = group.len();

        if len > 2 {
            group[1..len-2].chunks_exact_mut(2).for_each(|x| x.swap(0, 1));
        }
    }

    a.iter().collect()
}
```